# Git unable to write to objects file

Tags: git, github-desktop

The following message is displayed when trying to push to remote.

```
Enumerating objects: 65, done.
Counting objects: 100% (65/65), done.
Delta compression using up to 6 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (47/47), done.
Writing objects: 100% (51/51), 371.34 KiB | 2.12 MiB/s, done.
Total 51 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: unable to write file ./objects/05/de8428bbcb5425404f91296abd457eb8e99ff4: Permission denied
To ssh://gitlab:2222/path/repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] dynamic-components -> dynamic-components (unable to migrate objects to permanent storage)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gitlab:2222/path/repo.git'
```

This error is popping up several times now and I just can't seem to fix it.
According to other solutions, it is a local problem on my system.
It happens not all the time, i could not figure out what does the trick to run into this behavior

#### Env.

- Windows 10
- GitHub Desktop: Version 3.0.8
- Remote: GitLab 15.3.3

#### attempts

- running github desktop as admin
- pushing from cli (Windows CMD, as User and Admin)
- Checking Permissions on local .git/objects/...

---

## Update / Fix

i checked on the server i found the following

```
root@gitlab:/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/@hashed# find . -user root
./c6/f3/c6f3ac57944a531490cd39902d0f777715fd005efac9a30622d5f5205e7f6894.git/objects/3f
./c6/f3/c6f3ac57944a531490cd39902d0f777715fd005efac9a30622d5f5205e7f6894.git/objects/3f/eb0ea1ce53b0b5ef2e8b3bff1be8ee3177f2ed
./c6/f3/c6f3ac57944a531490cd39902d0f777715fd005efac9a30622d5f5205e7f6894.git/objects/05
./c6/f3/c6f3ac57944a531490cd39902d0f777715fd005efac9a30622d5f5205e7f6894.git/objects/05/7a46674746185781dc454df4e9f850222c7010
./c6/f3/c6f3ac57944a531490cd39902d0f777715fd005efac9a30622d5f5205e7f6894.git/objects/00
./c6/f3/c6f3ac57944a531490cd39902d0f777715fd005efac9a30622d5f5205e7f6894.git/objects/00/e25f2e05f216e53f7934f756fd33fcaa49e33e
./c6/f3/c6f3ac57944a531490cd39902d0f777715fd005efac9a30622d5f5205e7f6894.git/objects/13
./c6/f3/c6f3ac57944a531490cd39902d0f777715fd005efac9a30622d5f5205e7f6894.git/objects/13/d1489f9d3a110495e46b88206f2bdb53404b9a
```

changed all the files found to user `git` and the problem is solved.

Comment: This problem is on the server, and must be fixed on the server.

Comment: Please post error logs as text in a code block, not as images.

Comment: @joanis sorry, updated.

Comment: @Nick Much better, thanks!

Comment: @torek so the problem occurs due to permission issue within gitlab filesystem? Gitlab is running in docker and is self-hosted, i should be able to change permissions but not sure which ones to use.

Comment: Yes - looks like you found it on your own. An interesting question here is how these got to be root-owned in the first place (I have no idea what the answer to that is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occured due to permission problems on the server like @torek mentioned.

See *Update* section on initial question.